# Multiple search option in PHP MySQL AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to put multiple search option in PHP file through AJAX method. With one search (Search by name )option its working fine but when I put another search field ( Like Search by gender) then its search only with gender only. I can't do search for both of them at a same time. 
This is main index.php file

```
 This is tablepage.php file where ajax method calling + display data

<script charset="UTF-8">

    function pagination(page)
      {
          var search = $("input#fieldSearch").val();
          var record = $("select#pageRecord").val();
          var gender = $("select#fieldSearch1").val(); 
          if (search!=="")
          {
            dataString = 'starting='+page+'&gender='+ gender+'&name='+search+'&perpage='+ record+'&random='+Math.random();
        }

         else{
              dataString = 'starting='+page+'&perpage='+record+'&random='+Math.random();
            }

        $.ajax({
         url:"tablepage.php",
         data: dataString,
         type:"GET",
         success:function(data)
         {
            $('#divPageData').html(data);
          }
       });
     }

        function loadData()
       {
          var dataString;
          var search = $("input#fieldSearch").val();
          var record = $("select#pageRecord").val();
          var gender = $("select#fieldSearch1").val();
        dataString = '&gender=' + gender + 'name='+ search + '&perpage=' + record;


       $.ajax({
             url: "tablepage.php",
             type: "GET",
             data: dataString,
            success:function(data)
              {
                 $('#divPageData').html(data);
              }
        });
       }
    </script>

<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
   include('pagination_class.php');
   include('connect.php');

    if (isset($_GET['name']) and !empty($_GET['name'])){
       $name = $_GET['name'];
        $sql = "select * from fmaf where name like '%$name%'";

          }
           if (isset($_GET['gender']) and !empty($_GET['gender'])){
              $gender = $_GET['gender'];
            $sql = "select * from fmaf where gender = '$gender'";

           }
          else{

        $sql="select * from fmaf left join status ON fmaf.id = status.sid GROUP BY fmaf.id ";

        }

          if(isset($_GET['starting'])){ //starting page
                 $starting=$_GET['starting'];
                }else{
              $starting=0;
             }

           $recpage=$_GET['perpage'];

            $obj = new pagination_class($sql,$starting,$recpage);       
           $result = $obj->result;
       ?>
```

this is pagination.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#divLoading').ajaxStart(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn();
            $(this).html("<img src='loading.gif' /> ");
              }).ajaxStop(function(){
                $(this).fadeOut();
            });


           loadData();


          function loadData()
           {
             var dataString;
             var search = $("input#fieldSearch").val();
             var record = $("select#pageRecord").val();
             var gender = $("select#fieldSearch1").val();   


           dataString = '&gender=' + gender + 'name='+ search + '&perpage=' + record;


           $.ajax({
               url: "tablepage.php",
                 type: "GET",
             data: dataString,
               success:function(data)
               {
                $('#divPageData').html(data);
              }
        });
       }

          $("form#formSearch").submit(function()
            {
                 loadData();
               return false;
              });


                 });
```

Rest of pagination.class.php file is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just checking for singe GET parameter and if user want to find with name and gender vise than in that case i just add this code

```
if( !empty( $_GET['name']) && !empty( $_GET['gender']))
```